# Console time in second

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log

Is that possible to put the time of an action in second instead of milisecond with console time ?

Here is my code :

```
  console.log('start load cache');
  console.time('cache load ok executed in')
  // my loading from mongo
  console.timeEnd('cache load ok executed in')
```

What I get:

```
start load cache
cache load ok executed in: 47245.049ms
```

What I would like:

```
start load cache
cache load ok executed in: 47.245s
```

Thanks !

Comment: sec / 1000 = ms, just divide it by 1000

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky You should check your units or the operator because one second has slightly more than 0.001 milliseconds...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

console.time won't work for that, but you can always do it yourself:

```
console.log('start load cache');
const before = Date.now();
// my loading from mongo
const after = Date.now();
console.log('cache load ok executed in', (after - before) / 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a custom function and use it as below.

```
var getExecutionTime = function (fn) {
    var from = Date.now();
    fn();
    var to = Date.now();

    return to - from;
}

var execTime = getExecutionTime(function(){
// my loading from mongo
});
console.log("execution time in milisecond:", execTime/1000);
```